# Error copying layer structure

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to create new vector layer based on existing. Suddenly long  attribute names are truncated. Here is my code:

```
@staticmethod
def CreateNewEmptyLayer(sourceLayer, newLayerFileName):
    provider = sourceLayer.dataProvider()
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(newLayerFileName,provider.encoding(), provider.fields(), sourceLayer.wkbType(), provider.crs(),"ESRI Shapefile")
    if writer.hasError() != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        print("Error when creating shapefile: ", writer.errorMessage())
        return False;

    del writer;
    return True;
```

Source layer is MapInfo TAB file.

---

Added code to print info for source layers:

```
for field in provider.fields():
        print field.name(), field.typeName()
```

and result is ->source layer atrtribute names are NOT truncated to 11 symbols. So interesting is why QgsVectorFileWriter is truncating them?

Comment: Please  [edit] the question to specify the source datatype. If it isn't shapefile, then attribute name truncation for names beyond the dBase limit of 11 characters (bytes) would be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a limitation with dbase the .dbf file type of a shapefile.  It does not support field names greater than 10 characters.